# Fabric: Digits not working iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

I used Digits for mobile number OTP verification. After updating Xcode 7.3 to Xcode 8. I cant get OTP.

Now I getting the following error

> enqueueRequest:sessionStore:requestingUser:completion: Invalid parameter not satisfying: sessionStore

Can anyone Help me?

Comment: @Droppy yes its working xcode 7

Comment: @Droppy In xcode 7 i run iOS 9, In xcode 8 i run iOS 10.

Comment: Ok, it may be a problem with iOS version.So how can i solve this?  any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //just paste this 
 let authButton = DGTAuthenticateButton(authenticationCompletion: { (session, error) in
        if (session != nil) {
            // TODO: associate the session userID with your user model
            let message = "Phone number: \(session!.phoneNumber)"
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "You are logged in!", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: .none))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: .none)
        } else {
            NSLog("Authentication error: %@", error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
    authButton?.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(authButton!)
 }
```

Comment: if this answer helped you, an up vote would appreciate sir.